# Passing data to sub-components in Vue JS. Best practices?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, parent-child, vue-router, modularity

I'm confused about best practices for passing data from parent to child components and modularity strategies.

As I know there are 2 ways:

1. Fetching data in parent component and send Array/object to the child via props
2. Send parent_id to the child via props and fetching data within the child component

Let's assume a use case working with a product edit view, having:

- A parent component `product`
- A child `form` component to edit basic product information
- A child `related_products` component where other products can be linked/unlinked.

As per my experience, the first way works smoothly since it's all done in 1 request to the API: fetching a `product` object in parent component and passing through `props` the product itself to the `form` component and the nested objects to the `related_products` component. In addition, it can be done in `beforeRouteEnter` guard so the parent and all its children are shown with all the information at once. The cons I see here is that we have to send the correct object structure to the child component to avoid any error, having a strong dependency between components.

On the other hand, by sending the `parent_id` to every child component through `props` we release the parent from any logic. In this case, every child component acts as a "black box" and fetch/handles the information. The cons I see here is that we would have to perform 2 API requests for getting the product and the related products. In addition, the `beforeRouteEnter` is not viable at all, so we get an empty form/table until the data is retrieved.

This is not about how to code it, it's just about what's the best implementation as per your experience.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my experience is concerned, 1-st way is better. Parent component acts as "smart" and you have access to it's life cycle hooks in order to trigger your api-requests, reset timers, e.t.c... I would also suggest to use `vuex`, as it allows you to make clean interface of communication between your parent component and "outer world", utilizing `actions` and `getters`.

With that being said, your "dumb" child component communicates with it's parent through `props` and `emits` interface. And because it is "dumb" - it's easier to test it or utilize something like "storybook".

> we have to send the correct object structure to the child component to avoid any error

I guess, at the end of the day, you'll need correct object structure anyway, right? It could not be just random...

Comment: Thanks, I've been working in this way in the latest weeks and it seems to be the best approach. 
In regards to vuex, I'm still not convinced that it's a good practice for reusing components. Imagine a product form component that uses a vuex state to bind the v-models. Having more than 1 component at the same time will require dynamic vuex modules registration, 1 per each form which makes it really complex to handle. Otherwise, all components will be bound to the same state.